# Extracting div class text from HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrape data from OkCupid and get the relevant text data.

For example, the username data is stored in:

```
<div class="userinfo2015-basics-username"> AmericanMary666
```

Code to retrieve username

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://www.okcupid.com/profile/AmericanMary666") 

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
nameList = bsObj.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'userinfo2015-basics-username'})

for name in nameList:
    print(name.get_text())
```

It's not working and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `div` with class `userinfo2015-basics-username` in that link you provided.
My guess is that you are looking at the HTML source from a browser that is currently logged in. Try logging out or an incognito session and you will see a different source.
You may want to look into the requests module to authenticate and maintain a session between requests. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/